# Is Postgres sharding available on Aurora (AWS)

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, sharding, aurora, aws-aurora

I need to shard and/or partition my largeish Postgres db tables. The Postgres partitioning functionality seems crazy heavyweight (in terms of DDL). I see talk from <=2015 about pg_shard, but am unsure of the availabilty in Aurora, or even if one uses a different mechanism.

I would like something on the order of a "Key" Redshift-style distribution method. Furthermore, it would be great if there was some way to do it on a multi-colum basis (I can make a "fake concatenated column" if need be)

Comment: On Sep 25, 2018, they announced "Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL Compatibility Supports PostgreSQL 10" - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-aurora-postgresql-compatibility-supports-postgresql104/. They explicitly mentioned "native table partitioning", though there are features in PosgreSQL 11 that presumably are not included; see https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-11-sharding.html

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like an answer. I will make it the answer, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [@nathanlong](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8343/nathan-long)'s [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217414/is-postgres-sharding-available-on-aurora-aws#comment443911_217414) to my question:

> On Sep 25, 2018, they announced "Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL Compatibility Supports PostgreSQL 10" - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-aurora-postgresql-compatibility-supports-postgresql104/. They explicitly mentioned "native table partitioning", though there are features in PosgreSQL 11 that presumably are not included; see https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-11-sharding.html.